# How can I create a custom checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

Hello i am trying to create  a custom checkbox for my website like the image link provided. What would be the best way to go around doing this?
Many thanks.

[image: Custom checkboxes]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a CSS trick that actually works by hiding the checkbox (or radio), defining a label (which in all relevant browsers will turn the checkbox on/off) that will be the visual representation, and using the `:checked` and `+` selectors.

This is just a simple example:

```css
.foscheck input { display: none; }
.foscheck label { display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: red; }
.foscheck input:checked + label { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="foscheck">
  <input type="checkbox" id="fos1" />
  <label for="fos1"></label>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5buA/)

**Note:** For accessibility, you should have some text describing the checkbox in the `label`. I just wanted to illustrate the effect.

Comment: hey, thanks for this answer. i have done this following on from your solution. [js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vqhe2/) and was wondering how i get it to show like my image on the question next to each other. thanks.

Comment: @HAWKES08 Try adding `display: inline-block;` to the `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is your best bet, [this is a checkbox plugin for example](https://plugins.jquery.com/icheck/), but there are hundreds of them so something else may suit you better. Just google '[jquery custom checkbox](http://google.com?q=jquery%20custom%20checkbox)'.