# Customized HTML check box with labels

Tags: jquery, html, css

In a my website I need to customize check boxes with labels. What are the good libraries available to customize the appearance of check boxes

Example ibutton library

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491962/custom-checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can try this one too http://devgrow.com/iphone-style-switches/