# Highlight selected image

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I'm trying to highlight a selected image with a box around it, exactly the same as what appears for the 'hover'. Any ideas? I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work. The hover function works perfectly, but when clicked I need a box to appear around the image that stays, even when the cursor is moved away. I have pasted my code below. Thank you in advance!!

```
<html><head>

<style type="text/css">
.event {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

.swatch {
width: 57px;
height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 5px;
background-position: center center;
margin-top: 8px;
}

 .swatch:hover {
border: thin solid #999;
background-position: center center;
}

.selected {
border: thin solid #999;
}

.sq562-white {
background-image: url(../images/products/women/lifeguard_girlstee_white.jpg);
}


.sq562-red {
background-image: url(../images/products/women/lifeguard_girlstee_red.jpg);
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
// hide all the events
$("#bigCal p").hide();

$(".event a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#bigCal p").hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("." + id).show();
});
});
});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
<li class="event">
    <a id="red" href="#" >
        <div class="swatch sq562-white"></div>
    </a>
 </li>

 <li class="event">
    <a id="blue" href="#">
        <div class="swatch sq562-red"></div>
    </a>
</li>
</ul> 


<div id="bigCal">
<p style="display: block; margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:-54px;" class="all blue"><a    title="Red">Red</a></p>
<p style="display: none; margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:-54px;" class="all red"><a title="White">White</a></p>

</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491962/custom-checkbox/6492222#6492222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can also test this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// hide all the events
$("#bigCal p").hide();

$(".event a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //remove the previous selected item
    $(".swatch").removeClass("selected");
    //select the current item
    $(".swatch", this).addClass("selected");
    $("#bigCal p").hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("." + id).show();
  });
});
```

And a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/SNUhB/2/

Comment: Thank you!! This works perfectly, only I find it conflicts with other javascripts / jQuery scripts in my code (not listed above). But that's a separate issue that I need to address. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `onclick` to add the `.selected` class (with jQuery, can also be done with only JavaScript):

```
$(".swatch").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Am having difficulty getting it to work. I added this into my head:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".swatch").click(function() {
    this.addClass("selected");
});
</script>

But no luck. Perhaps that wasn't what I was meant to do? Sorry, newbie here!

Comment: @user2132851 I edited my answer just then; you'll have to put `$(this)` instead of `this` because you're using jQuery on it.

Comment: If you want to toggle the class (add class onclick then remove on next click), you can replace `addClass` with `toggleClass`.