# Display button after 5x checkboxes have been ticked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, sprite

I have  list of check boxes using css sprite.
The check boxes are fine but I would like it so that when a users has check all the boxes it then (and only then) displays a button at the bottom of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have jfiddle but dont get the whole - must be accompanied by code?

TY

Comment: You can do this with jquery.

Comment: use javascript/jquery

Comment: I can see lots of Jquery checkboxes demos but not to make a button appear at the end.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eZ5Tm/

Answer (score 1):

In theory this can be done with only css, by using the `:checked` selector, in combination with the `+` sibling selector. The css would look something like this:

```
.checkbox:checked + label + .checkbox:checked + label + .checkbox:checked + label + .checkbox:checked + label + .checkbox:checked + label + #the-button {
    display: block;
}
```

In theory this should work, but when I tried it in jsFiddle it acted a bit strange. I don't think this is a very workable solution anyway, cause it is hard to debug and requires your html to have a certain structure that can not change.

In real life this would be done with a few lines of jQuery. The code I came up with looks like this:

```
// cache he collection of checkboxes
var $checkboxes = $('#js-solution .checkbox');
// when a checkbox changes
$checkboxes.change(function() {
    // filter out the ones that are checked
    var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked');
    // if the number of checked ones is 5
    if ($checked.length == 5) {
        // show the button
       $('#the-js-button').css('display', 'block');
    // if the number of checked ones is not 5
    } else {
        // hide the button
        $('#the-js-button').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

The comments should be sufficient to make you understand what happens, but feel free to ask.

I put both solutions next to each other in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7GN7q/1/
The css solution does not work for me, but I think it is a Chrome thing, cause I don't see what is invalid, in while inspecting the style does get applied, and uncheking and checking the `display:block`in the inspector does make it work. In real life I would go for the js solution anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look and report back.

Comment: I am getting the checkboxes to display but having issues with the button which appears prior to any boxes being checked.
Also is there a way I can use two checkboxes I have designed?
checkbox1.png & checkbox2.png or with sprite checkbox.png

Comment: yes you can. check out Ryan Fait's implementation. (google it)

Comment: the fact that your button appears before the checkboxes are checked is probably because you did not hide the button by default (in your css). Line 14 in my fiddle. Using custom checboxes and sprites is of course possible but that would be an entirely different question, it has nothing to do with the answer I provided.

Comment: I c&p your code but still having button display issue - I tested line 14 via fiddle and understand what you mean.
Could it be that I am not linking Javascript files properly? Literally just pasted the .js code into a new document checkbox.js linked on page (did I do something wrong?) 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/checkbox.js"></script>

Comment: did you put the code inside a jquery ready function: `$(document).ready(function() { //code goes here // });` And did you load the jQuery library? Perhaps you can post a link to a live example, so I can have a look...

Comment: Thanks Peter! That was it - your solution is working now. Could we progress a step further and replace checkboxes with images.

Comment: Kind of similar to this but clicking the actual img/checkbox
http://jsfiddle.net/teHwE/

Comment: you should post a new question for the custom checkboxes, after you did some research that is... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491962/custom-checkbox

Comment: $('#the-js-button').toggle($checked.length == 5)

Answer (score 1):

You may as well see that with selector  **~** , input checked doesn't need to be in a row.
It can just be 5 out of ten for instance. forked jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/sqRaG/

```
.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox:checked ~.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox:checked~ .checkbox:checked ~ #the-button {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is spot on - Thanks to both Peter & GC. Now how would I go about replacing the checkbox with <img> - I looked at other tutorials but no luck.

Comment: to replace checkbox with image visually is done using input + its label.Place image in label. set checbox on absolute and and left very away from the screen. they're you are.If label and checkbox with correct attributes id and for.

Comment: if you add a sixth :checked selector, you can hide again the button.