# Clicking div to toggle checkbox and change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I've got a site built from many divs. Nearly all div's have the same class (for CSS) and different id. Here's a part of the code:

```
<div class="box" id="testbox">
<img src=""><br>
Name<br><input name="choice" value="1" id="name" type="checkbox" onchange="onCheckboxChanged(); checkTotal();">
</div>
```

When I click anywhere in this div I want to check/uncheck it's checkbox (which is hidden so it can't be clicked) and this will toggle onCheckboxChanged() (unlocks more checkboxes) and checkTotal() (adds values from checked checkboxes). Because of that. clicked div's must first check if a checkbox is enabled and then check/uncheck it. Also I want it to change the background of only this div. I would prefer a solution that uses only html/css/js.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for "solutions". It's for help finding a solution. Show us that you have at least attempted writing some javascript or jquery to solve this.

Comment: All I needed was actually to switch from divs to labels. Of course I had written onCheckboxChanged() and checkTotal() before posting this question here. Sorry for misrepresentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Use it instead of your div and it will basically do what you need. You can use the `disabled` property on the checkboxes to enable/disable them.

Comment: Co label will behave like div but give me more options like onclick="toggleCheckbox('name');"?

Comment: @Hayaku I suggest you try it and read some docs about it. As a rule of thumb, you should use a label element whenever you use a form element (input, select, textarea), but in this case, it will help you further. When you click a label, the associated form element will receive the click too (hint: even if it is hidden).

Comment: This could also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491962/custom-checkbox/6492222#6492222

Comment: I could do everything I needed after I switched divs to labels. Thanks!

Comment: @Hayaku Explore all the HTML5 elements, there are some quite useful ones ;).

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("testbox").onclick = function(e){
    var nameCheck = document.getElementById("name");
    nameCheck.checked = !nameCheck.checked;
    nameCheck.onchange();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQkAZ/) - you could do something like this, though I think using a hidden checkbox instead of an attribute on the div could be superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.box').click(function(){

   if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
            /// do other stuffs
        }
   else
        { 
            $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked');
            /// do other stuffs
        }
});
```